# "When a file is created or modified (property only)" with 3 trigger conditions will never run

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, power-automate, flow, power-platform

I have this document library named "Customer Share" and inside it, it contains "Clients" folder >> then inside the Clients Folder we have clients sub-folders.

Now I want to trigger the flow only when files are added to the clients sub-folders:

[image: clet.png]

Now I added these 3 Trigger Conditions:

1. `@greater(length(split(triggerOutputs()?['body/{Path}'],'/')),2)` // so I can be sure that the file is added inside the customer sub-folder
2. `@greaterOrEquals(indexOf('Customer Share/Clients/',triggerOutputs()?['body/{Path}']),0)` // so I can be sure that the sub-folder is under the Clients folder
3. `@equals(triggerOutputs()?['body/{IsFolder}'],false)` // only files no folders

[image: johnjohn123_0-1689206372239.png]

but the flow will never run.

any advice?

Comment: Do you want to run flow if new files uploaded directly inside "Clients" folder?

Comment: @GaneshSanap no only insdie the client subfolder such as /clients/clientA/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there with your trigger conditions. You just need to slightly adjust your first 2 conditions as explained below:

1. In your 1st condition, use 3 instead of 2 as array will have more than 3 elements after split:

```
@greater(length(split(triggerOutputs()?['body/{Path}'],'/')),3)
```

2. Syntax of `indexOf` function is like: `indexOf('<text>', '<searchText>')`. So, change the parameter positions in your trigger condition like:

```
@greaterOrEquals(indexOf(triggerOutputs()?['body/{Path}'],'Customer Share/Clients/'),0)
```

Here are the all 3 trigger conditions working for me:

[image]

Also, configure your flow trigger like this:

[image]

Comment: ok thanks it worked well now, but can you advice why `split(triggerOutputs()?['body/{Path}']` will always generate empty item inside the array?

Comment: Generally folder path of the file will be like `Customer Share/Clients/ClientA/` and when you split this string based on `/` character, it will return 4 elements including empty item (element after last `/`).

Answer (score 1):

You can try following trigger conditions to achieve your requirements

1. To ensure that file is added insides `Clients` folder only

   `@equals(contains(triggerOutputs()?['body/{Path}'], 'Customer Share/Clients/'), true)`
2. To ensure that file is only added inside `Clients/ClientXX` folder

   `@greater(length(split(triggerOutputs()?['body/{Path}'], '/')), 3)`
3. To ensure only files not folders

   `@equals(triggerOutputs()?['body/{IsFolder}'],false)`

Comment: ok thanks it worked well now, but can you advice why split(triggerOutputs()?['body/{Path}'] will always generate empty item inside the array beside the other list items?\